# Problem: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable on radio field using WTForms and Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of days.

I have a form defined that contains the following:

```py
class CheckInForm(FlaskForm): 
    checkin_email = HiddenField('Email Address')
    checkin_site =  RadioField('Which Site?',validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Check In!')
```

When a GET request is issued at the defined route I want to dynamically set the choices and am using this code to do that:

```py
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #
        # Original request for form
        if len(request.args) == 0:
            form = CheckInForm()
            sites = Sites.query.all()
            choices = []
            for site in sites:
                choice = ( site.sitecode, site.sitename)
                choices.append(choice)
            form.checkin_site.choices = choices     
            form.checkin_email.data=current_user.email 
            return render_template('CheckIn.html', **RenderTemplateParms.get(title='Check In', form=form))
```

The HTML for the page using Jinja is:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="content-section">
    <h1>Check In to Fly!</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.checkin_site.label(class="form-control-label font-weight-bold") }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ legend }}</legend>
            {% for subfield in form.checkin_site %}
                <div class="form-check">
                    {{ subfield(class="form-control form-control-lg form-check-input ") }}
                    {{ subfield.label }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </fieldset>    
    </form>
</div>
        

{% endblock content %}
```

When the POST request is received the following code is executed:

```py
    form = CheckInForm()      
    if form.validate_on_submit():     
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.checkin_email.data)
        user.flight_status = form.checkin_site.data
        db.session.commit() 
        chkin = Checkin()
        chkin.checkin_site = form.checkin_site.data
        chkin.checkin_date = date.today()
        chkin.checkin_email = current_user.email
        chkin.commit()  
        flash('Have a great day. Be safe','success')   
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
```

Then I receive the following error in my trace:

```
ERROR:sadasy:Exception on /checkin [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/main/routes.py", line 248, in CheckIn
    if form.validate_on_submit():
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 100, in validate_on_submit
    return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 310, in validate
    return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 152, in validate
    if not field.validate(self, extra):
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 195, in validate
    self.pre_validate(form)
  File "/Users/jeffsinason/development/sadasy-MMS/sadasy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 471, in pre_validate
    for v, _ in self.choices:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This problem has been bewildering me for several days.

Thank you in advance for your help...

Comment: humm, i give a fast look i your code, i think you are missing the hidden checkin_email in your html template, this is probally ocasioning NoneType in Post validation

Comment: That was one of the problems i was addressing early on.  The hidden field is being added via the ```{{ form.hidden_tag() }} ``` tag in the HTML.  When I look at the HTML generated I see:
```<div class="content-section">
    <h1>Check In to Fly!</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input id="checkin_email" name="checkin_email" type="hidden" value="jeffsinason@gmail.com">
<
```

Comment: So, I've continued to work on this an found that when I readded the choices in the POST it works fine as I expected.  I added the line: ``` form.checkin_site.choices = checkin_site_choices()  ``` where the checkin_site_choices() function builds the choices to be used on the RadioField.  Seems like strange behavior to me.